# Class decorators in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.5

Is there a way I can make **class decorators** work on **Google App Engine**, which is limited to **`Python 2.5`**?

Or let me rephrase that: is it possible to alter the behavior of Python's parser from the same process that it is already executing? Example:

**good.py:**

```
alter_python_parser()
import bad
```

**bad.py:**

```
@decorated
class Foo(object): pass
```

Or is this maybe just plainly impossible.

Explanation: I want to use a third party library that heavily uses class decorators, and don't want to fork it and maintain my own version. An alternative would be to run my code on **`Typhoon App Engine`** with a newer python, but I fear Google won't upgrade their Python version for a loooong time...

**`EDIT:`**

How about creating a [new-style import hook](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) that would do string substitution on-the-fly and load the module from memory? That should be possible. I'll give it a try, if there's no implementation already out there.

But how can I parse `Python 2.6+` code from `Python 2.5`? Is there a python-only parser? What does `PYPY` use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Decorators are just syntactic sugar. Just change instances of decorator usage, that is,

```
@decorated
class Foo(object): pass
```

becomes

```
class Foo(object): pass
Foo = decorated(Foo)
```

You can't, realistically, change the parser.

Though, you could automate the above process using the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html) (in a new version of Python).

Comment: I know it's only syntactic sugar. But I don't want to maintain massive changes to code that already works. So, `ast` would probably help. If there would be a Python implementation of the `_ast` module, I could maybe do it on-the-fly with an import hook...

Comment: It'll only work with the ast module above version 2.6. I doubt you'll be able to do it on the fly.

Comment: jfyi, I've created an import hook that will fix the class decorators using the `ast` tree from `lib2to3`: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/seven

Comment: congratulations, this is an impressive achievement.