# Python2.6+ code parser

Tags: python, python-2.5

Is there a `parser` that:

- is able to parse `Python`**`2.6+`** code, and
- can be run in `Python`**`2.5`** (python-only, no `C` extensions allowed)?

NOTE: This is somewhat related to [my previous quostion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307419/class-decorators-in-python-2-5) about class decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [lib2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) can, all you need to do is to provide it with the right **Grammar** file (get the source code for the Python you want and copy *Grammar/Grammar*).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've created some simple fixers that convert `Python 2.7` code to `Python 2.5` using `lib2to3` from the `2.7 stdlib`, and an import hook that does the conversion on-the-fly: https://github.com/aatiis/seven