# Is it possible to use wsgiservice with Python 2.5 (Google App Engine)?

Tags: google-app-engine, syntax, wsgi, python-2.5

I would like to use the [WsgiService](http://packages.python.org/WsgiService/) library to write a REST service on [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) (GAE). The two features I like most are the way it automatically outputs a certain format (JSON, XML, ...) depending on the file name ending in the request path. Also it is able to directly map parts of the path to variables using regular expressions.

[The official tutorial](http://packages.python.org/WsgiService/tutorial.html) uses class decorators which are not available in Python 2.5 and therefore GAE throws an invalid syntax exception. Stack Overflow question *[Class decorators in Python 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307419/class-decorators-in-python-2-5)* mentions that class decorators are just syntactic sugar and can be replaced with backwards compatible code. Also the wsgiservice documentation doesn't mention that Python 2.6 is strictly required. Unfortunately I was not able to replace the class decorators to make it run on GAE.

Is it possible to replace the class decorators in the tutorial to run with Python 2.5? If not, is there any other library which provides the above functionality while being GAE compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PKG-INFO file of WsgiService contains the following line

`Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6`

and therefore does not suit GAE (Python 2.5).

The requested features can be achieved with different URL mappings, as described here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html#URL_Mappings

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used WsgiService, but decorators in Python 2.6 are really [just function calls with a special syntax](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator). So if you see the following code:

```
@MyDecorator
def myfunction():
    mycode
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
def myfunction():
    mycode
myfunction = MyDecorator(myfunction)
```

So if you can be bothered writing all your code in that style, it should still work (assuming the other code is Python 2.5 compliant).

To make it clear what you are doing, I would probably put the decorator in a comment above, like:

```
# @MyDecorator
```

Edit: If the decorator takes arguments, it must return a function, and *that* function is called with the function being wrapped:

```
@MyDecorator(arg1, arg2)
def myfunction():
    mycode
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
def myfunction():
    mycode
myfunction = MyDecorator(arg1, arg2)(myfunction)
```

Comment: thanks for you response. two questions: if the decorator itself takes arguments, is the replaced function/class parameter passed as the first or last argument? also how can you find out what version of Python a lib requires? (I'm relatively new to Python, couldn't find the above in any docs...)

Comment: 1. Good question. Actually neither; if the decorator takes arguments, it must return a function, and the replaced function is passed *to that*. I'll edit the answer to show an example (since there's no space here). 2. There's no specific way to do this; just consult the relevant docs.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, unfortunately WsgiService does require Python 2.6, replacing the decorators simply made the syntax exception occur in one of the wsgiservice modules..